Should the integral of a function between two inputs equal the integral of the inverse function from the values the two inputs map to?
Let's say you have a 1-dimensional rod with a bijective mass-density function $\rho(x)$, where $x$ is the distance measured from the center of the rod. The mass between some two distances $x_1$ and $x_2$, $M$, is
$$M = \int_{x_1}^{x_2}\rho(x)dx.$$
Now, since the function is bijective, all the points (distances along the rod) are going to correspond with unique densities and vice-versa. So the mass of the rod between the points whose densities are $\rho(x_1)$ and $\rho(x_2)$ should be equal to the original integral:
$$M=\int_{\rho(x_1)}^{\rho(x_2)}x(\rho)d\rho.$$
Based on that reasoning, I would think it would hold that, if $f(x)$ is bijective, then
$$\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(x)dx=\int_{f(x_1)}^{f(x_2)}f^{-1}(x)dx.$$
Now, it's widely said that $\ln(x)$ is the inverse function of $f(x)=e^x$, which implies that $e^x$ is bijective (since it has an inverse). However, computing the above integrals for $f(x)=e^x$, $x_1=1$ and $x_2=3$ shows that the equality doesn't hold:
$$\int_{1}^{3}e^xdx\neq\int_{e}^{e^3}\ln(x)dx.$$
Since I don't see where I went wrong with 1-dimensional rod example, I thought about what it means for a function to be bijective. A bijective function is one that is both injective and surjective. An injective function is one such that if  $x_1\neq x_2$, then $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$, simple enough.
But a surjective function is one whose "image of its domain is equal to it's codomain." This confuses me because you can define "domain"  and "codomain" however you want (as long as the latter is a superset of the image; the codomain is a set which contains all of the outputs of the function, by definition); I can define $f(x)=e^x$ but only for $x>0$ and for the codomain to be the positive real numbers. Is $f(x)$ now bijective, then? If so, why doesn't my equality hold/where did I go wrong?
Also, while researching for this, I learned about a function's "natural domain": the set of all values of the argument for which the function is defined, wihtout any "man-made" restrictions on that set. This got me wondering, would the image of a function's natural domain define a "natural codomain" set, and that the equality I wrote above only holds if a function is injective and the codomain is the image of the natural domain (i.e., surjective with the domain being the natural domain and the codomain being the image of the natural domain)?
Thank you.

Your first conclusion $M=\int_{\rho(x_1)}^{\rho(x_2)}x(\rho)d\rho$ is wrong; it should be $M=\int_{\rho(x_1)}^{\rho(x_2)}\rho,dx(\rho)$. You can think of the integral as a weighted sum of the values of the integrand, with weights given by the "$dx$" part. Intuitively, the densities of the rod in places where the density is changing more slowly should count more than the densities in the places where the density is changing quickly. See u-substitution.

@Karl I'm very sorry for the late reply, I did not have email notifications set up and forgot about this. Please forgive me. I don't understand why $M=\int_{\rho (x_1)}^{\rho (x_2)} \rho ,dx(\rho)$; is this not the same equation in the question body but with the limits changed from $x_1$ and $x_2$ to the densities at those points? Assuming the first integral is correct, how can this one also be correct? I'm assuming that changing $\rho (x)$ and $dx$ for $\rho$ and $dx(\rho)$ is arbitrary and doesn't affect the underlying math as it is simply notation for the density and distance quantities.

By $dx(\rho)$ I mean $\frac{dx}{d\rho}d\rho$ (assuming the necessary derivative exists). The point is that to calculate the mass of the rod, you add up the masses of tiny segments of the rod, and each segment has length $dx$ and density $\rho$, so you multiply these two quantities. You can change your independent variable (which changes how you express these two quantities), but don't change what you're computing. "$x(\rho)d\rho$" is an absolute position $x$ multiplied by a "density increment" $d\rho$ - why would we expect this to give us the mass of something?

@Karl Ah I get it now. Thanks for sticking with me.
